# Basic fluid dynamics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow

[image: figure]

> "A hypodermic syringe contains a medicine with the density of water (Figure 6). The barrel of the syringe has a cross-sectional area A = 2.50 * 10^-5 m2,
> and the needle has a cross-sectional area a = 1.00 * 10^-8 m2. In the absence of a force on the plunger, the pressure everywhere is 1.00 atm. A force F of magnitude 2.00 N acts on the plunger, making medicine squirt horizontally from the needle. Determine the speed of the medicine as it leaves the needle’s tip."

This is problem for study.
And I'd want to know if we should assume the plunger moves at constant speed when solving this problem.
Does using ΔP = F/A, imply the plunger is moving at constant speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P=F/A$, by itself  does not put any boundary on plunger speed, unless there are specified pressure and/or force constancy/variability conditions in the task description, which there is none. However, task asks to determine exit speed of liquid, and if this speed would not be a constant value, then there  would be no point asking it. So it implies that $\vec v$ is constant.

According to Bernoulli's principle $${\frac {v^{2}}{2}}+gz+{\frac {p}{\rho }}={\text{constant}} \tag 1$$

, $\vec v$ can only fluctuate if pressure $p$ fluctuates too (assuming same elevation $z$, i.e. we measure pressure across syringe center axis).
So, for fluctuating exit pressure from syringe, you can do this by fluctuating pressure/force on the plunger itself.

Hence, as we deduced that exit speed $v$ must be constant,- input pressure on plunger must be constant too, and so plunger speed must be constant also.

From the (1) you can easily find out $$\frac {v_{~exit}^{2}}{2}-\frac{v_{~plunger}^{2}}{2}  \tag 2$$

because you have already a pair of pressures $p_1,p_2$, hence you know **a lower bound** of medicine speed already from Bernoulli's principle alone. To find real liquid exit speed you need to "patch" lower bound by a plunger speed (or medicine speed in a barrel). I'll leave this task for you to find out yourself.